# Python Requests post

Tags: python, python-requests

I have tried to  login in a website using requests. I have seen several inputs on the code of login page what inputs should I incude in the requests post. I have written the below code but it is not working could you check it.

Below is the HTML code of the login form of the website and my script. Could you check it.

```
#login form HTML Code
```

```
<input autocapitalize="off" autofocus="autofocus" class="login-email" id="login-email" name="session_key" placeholder="Email" tabindex="1" type="text"/>

<input aria-required="true" class="login-password" id="login-password" name="session_password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="1" type="password">

<input class="login submit-button" id="login-submit" tabindex="1" type="submit" value="Sign in"/>

<input name="isJsEnabled" type="hidden" value="false">

<input id="loginCsrfParam-login" name="loginCsrfParam" type="hidden" value="73b525bd-1656-4ee0-879f-b4c1d7959656"/>         


#This is the code


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

c = requests.Session()
login_url = "#some url"
results = c.get(login_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.content, 'html.parser')

key = soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")

authenticity_token = key[u'value']

print(authenticity_token)
payload = {"session_key": "......", "session_password": "....", "isJsEnabled": "false", "loginCsrfParam": "authenticity_token"}


c.post("#some url", data = payload)
r = c.get("#some url")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup2.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
payload = {"session_key": "......", "session_password": "....", "isJsEnabled": "false", "loginCsrfParam": "authenticity_token"}
```

there, you post "authencity_token" as a string, you want the variable value, so remove those quotes :

```
payload = {"session_key": "......", "session_password": "....", "isJsEnabled": "false", "loginCsrfParam": authenticity_token}
```

Comment: Thanks for your note. I have tried but not working. What about other inputs like submit button or isJsEnabled. Do we have to post them also?

Comment: Of course, you have to post as much as you can. Mimic the "normal" use as much as possible.
Also check request headers, and post them too...